# Animation on initial page load(isotope)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I would like to animate on page load, like in [this example](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wn_zKT6mCVSBFyD04VMYeDPIIvsbuGyQT28MFKMpgrI/edit?usp=sharing)(click to watch).
Use isotope plugin

```
var $container = $('.masonry-container').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.masonry',
  masonry: {
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: '.masonry'
  },
  transitionDuration: '2.4s'
});
// reveal all items after init
var iso = $container.data('isotope');
$container.isotope( 'reveal', iso.items );
```

How do you run an animation on page load? THX!

Answer (score 0):

Complete! Use wow.js+animate.css
Code

```
setTimeout(function() {

var $grid = $('.masonry-container').imagesLoaded( function() {

  $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.masonry',
        percentPosition: true,
        columnWidth: '.masonry'
  });
});

    $(".hide-masonry").show();

},3000);

new WOW().init();
```

And add class to dynamically loaded blocks: `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 masonry nopadding wow zoomIn animated" wow-data-duration="<?echo $i;?>s" data-wow-delay="<?echo $i;?>00ms">`